# Errors with FFMPEG on Ubuntu 16.04 While Using AMERGE: Segmentation Fault, et al

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, audio, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault

[ffmpeg version info below, as well as OS version info.]

I am trying to use the sidechaincompression filter along with the amerge filter in ffmpeg for ducking voiceover audio over an audio bed.

The two files have the same sample rate and the same format, and both are single channel (mono).

When I use the following CLI command:

> ffmpeg -i padded591.flac -i gr-mono.flac -filter_complex
>   "[0:a:0]asplit=2[sc][mix];[1:a:0][sc]sidechaincompress[compr];[compr][mix]amerge"
>   -ac 1 output-merged.flac

I get the following set of errors:

> [Parsed_sidechaincompress_1 @ 0x30fc660] No channel layout for input 1
>   [Parsed_amerge_2 @ 0x30fcea0] No channel layout for input 1
>   [Parsed_amerge_2 @ 0x30fcea0] Input channel layouts overlap: output
>   layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
>   [flac @ 0x30fb9e0] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample

and:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I've tried different file types, different file orders, even running e2fsck on the system, to no avail.

Any assistance with resolving this would be very much appreciated!

**ffmpeg version info**
ffmpeg version N-77827-g9006567 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-5ubuntu2) 20160108
  configuration: 
  libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101

**OS version info** 
Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (development branch) [x64]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this as a bug to ffmpeg, I was instructed to try the latest version.  Apparently, during my struggles, they had already found and patched the bug.

Answer: Latest ffmpeg version fixes bug.